# moving specific characters of a string to the end of it MIPS

Tags: string, assembly, character, mips

I wanted to know how i can push certain types of characters in a string to the end of it for example: 
I have

```
.data 

string: .asciiz "H3LL0 W0RLD"
```

with a loop I wanted to scan the string and if a number is encountered it is put in the last position so the output would be "HLL WRLD300"

I have already done the coding for the length of the string and I also know how to scan each character but I can't seem to be able to recognize the number and also push it to the end.

this is the code for the string's length:

```
length:

li $v0, 0
lbu $t1, ($a0)          
for: 
    beqz $t1, end_for   
    addi $v0, $v0, 1    

    addi $a0, $a0, 1    
    lbu $t1, ($a0)      

    j for
end_for:

    jr $ra
```

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to have a separate buffer for the resulting string. Iterate over the original string once and copy all the non-digits to the other buffer, then iterate over the original string once more and copy all the digits.

Comment: ok that could do it but how do i recognize the digits

Comment: is there a way of doing it without using a buffer, by just working on the string?

Comment: Iterate over the string, when you find a digit you move all the characters after it one step to the left, and then place the digit at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to solve your problem would be to use "bltu" (branch on less than) to see if the character you're looking at is smaller than 0, or larger than 9. If it satisfies either of those conditions it must not be a number, so push that to a buffer. Afterwards, you can do the same thing but this time find the characters whose values are between 0 and 9 inclusively, and push those to your buffer (adding the digits to the end of your string).

If you're not keen on using a buffer you can instead just use the shifting method: go through the string and when you find a digit (using the aforementioned technique) you save that digit, and iterate through the rest of the string, moving everything one index to the left. after reaching the end, you add the saved digit. Do so until you've travelled the original length of your string and voila, you're done!

Comment: thank you i used the approach without the buffer and it worked